# Are MySQL-InnoDb locks smart?

Tags: mysql

The following queries

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Users) WHERE Id = 1
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Users Where Id = 1
```

are equivalent. But according to documentation, in Serializable mode all selects are made in LOCK IN SHARED MODE. Does it mean in the first example the whole Users table will be locked in shared mode?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Open two different connections, start two transactions and check the result.

Comment: How can I check the records which have read locks?

Comment: also specify the storage engine used

Comment: This is more about query optimizers than about locks. A decent query optimizer should rewrite the subquery to the simple statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept of share mode locks. From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

> SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE sets a
>   shared mode lock on the rows read. A
>   shared mode lock enables other
>   sessions to read the rows but not to
>   modify them.

So there can be concurrent reads. Only **modifications** will be delayed until your query gets executed.